# I'm trying to capture a series of tags between two tags in an xml document using a regular expression

Tags: regex, xml

I'm trying to capture a series of tags between two tags in an xml document using a regular expression but its capturing every occurrence in the document.

```
<Mods>
<unsignedlong>123456</unsignedlong>
</Mods>
<Administrators>
<unsignedlong>12345678910111213</unsignedlong>
</Administrators>
<Banned>
<unsignedlong>12345678910111213</unsignedlong>
</Banned>
```

That's the code i need to grab the following from.

```
<unsignedlong>12345678910111213</unsignedlong>
```

I have been using

```
<unsignedLong>(?<ModID>\d+)</unsignedLong>
```

But this returns all of the values from the whole file - I need to a string to single out the unsigned longs from

`<Mods></Mods>`

Edit

This is for use within a web application that recognises regular expressions

Comment: Use XML parser (read about XPath)

Comment: Please don't parse XML with regexes if at all possible :)

Comment: @ErikJohnson sorry this is not possible as it's being used through a web app to phrase a config file

Comment: *"I need to a string to single out the unsigned longs from"* -- what does that mean? What is your desired output exactly? Can you provide more example data and explain why it's not correct?

Comment: i have 3 sections in a cfg one mods one administrators and one banned in the web app i use the `<unsignedLong>(?<ModID>\d+)</unsignedLong>` to get the results how ever this returs the values of all results in the cfg not just for those in the above sections i need something to add to `<unsignedLong>(?<ModID>\d+)</unsignedLong>` that when entered into the web app will look for `<unsignedlong>12345678910111213</unsignedlong>` inside of the `<Mods></Mods>` section i hope this makes it a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you require with a couple of modifications:

```
// Match a Regex and Do Stuff
public void showMatch(string input, string expr)
{
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, expr);

    // Index
    int num = 0;

    // "For each match in the match collection, Do this"
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        string tm = m.ToString();
        num++;
        if (num == 1)
        {
            // Do Stuff if 1 match.
        }
        if (num == 2)
        {
            // Do Stuff if 2 matches.
        }
```

To match match what you want you'd use this:

```
showMatch(input, @"(?:[0-9]+){17}");
```